# Combining two arrays in to one in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

This is the array i have.

```
   Array
   (
[0] => Array
    (
        [FoodItem] => Array
            (
                [id] => B102
                [food_item_title] => Prown cocktail
                [active] => 1
            )

        [MenuFoodItem] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 2
            )

    )

)
```

I want to combine FoodItem and MenuFoodItem array into one as following using native php or cake php

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [FoodItem] => Array
            (
                [id] => B102
                [food_item_title] => Prown cocktail
                [active] => 1
                [menu_id] => 2
            )
    )

)
```

Comment: As this looks like data returned by Model it might be better to reorganise your model logic ;-) And a bit off topic - `prawn` is spelled with an `a` not an `o`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using blow code.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($datas as $data)
{
    $result[$i]['FoodItem'] = $data['FoodItem'];
    $result[$i]['FoodItem']['menu_id'] = $data['MenuFoodItem']['menu_id'];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this

$arr is the array to work with

```
$arr_merged = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
    $arr_merged[$i]['FoodItem'] = array_merge($arr[$i]['FoodItem'], $arr[$i]['MenuFoodItem']);
}
```

Comment: well your code will work only if array has single element....but what if it does not..??

Answer (score 0):

Array Operators: $a + $b Union of $a and $b.

The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php